# Issue authenticating Tenant when using SPMT in powershell on VM

Tags: powershell, migration, sharepoint-online, file-transfer

Bit of a specific issue, for context I'm working on a vm inside a vm for a client.

I'm attempting to migrate their files using the official Sharepoint migration tool.

When I run all my tests using the GUI for the tool everything works fine however I need to fully automate this process. I have written a PowerShell script based off the official documentation, however whenever I run the process through PowerShell, it gets as far as starting a session, loading the jobs and connecting (using the same credentials and source file as when using the GUI) but then when it should start the migration it errors, from looking in the logs I can see a repeating error with getting the tenant details for the user details, other than that I'm at a loss for what could be causing this.

Any help or thoughts on what to try would be appreciated as the fall back option is migrating the files through a custom PnP PowerShell script that I really don't want to write if I can use the official tool

Answer (score 0):

I didn’t see any responses, so I thought I might point you in the right direction.

The following two part article helped me to get started.

**File Server Migration to SharePoint Online using PowerShell - Part I**:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/file-server-migration-to-sharepoint-online-using-spmt-powershell-part

**File Server Migration to SharePoint Online using PowerShell - Part II**:
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/file-server-migration-to-sharepoint-online-using-spmt-powershell-part2

You will also need to make sure that you have SharePoint Site Collection Admin Rights. The quickest method is to use the Set-SPOUser PowerShell Cmdlet, via the SharePoint Online Module.

**Set-SPOUser -Site https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/marketing -LoginName melissa.kerr@contoso.com -IsSiteCollectionAdmin $true**

Let me know if you have any questions or run into any issues. I’ll do my best to check back again, sometime in the near future.

Good Luck!